# Signing a Bitcoin transaction in Node

Tags: node.js, typescript, bitcoin

I have been implementing transactions in a NodeJS environment and have been using guides like https://learnmeabitcoin.com/technical/ecdsa#sign to understand the code behind it.

I have written a function that signs a transaction, but some part of the code is flawed as verifying the signature produced by the below function keeps returning `false`. The `verify` function I've written should be working correctly, as it returns `true` for signatures produced by a [a thirty party library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tiny-secp256k1).

Imported functions such as `bufferToBigInt`, `pointMultiply`, `pointAdd`, `modulo` have been tested and should be working correctly.

I've added type annotations below to make it easier to understand variable's types.

```
export const sign = (hashOfMessage: Buffer, privateKey: Buffer) => {
  const randomNumber: bigint = bufferToBigInt(generatePrivateKey());
  const randomPoint: Buffer = pointMultiply(GENERATOR_POINT, randomNumber);
  const randomPointX: bigint = extractX(randomPoint);
  const privateKeyAsNumber: bigint = bufferToBigInt(privateKey);
  const r: bigint = modulo(randomPointX, ORDER);
  const s: bigint = modulo(
    modInv(randomNumber, ORDER) *
      (bufferToBigInt(hashOfMessage) + randomNumber * privateKeyAsNumber),
    ORDER
  );
  const sLow: bigint = s > ORDER / 2n ? ORDER - s : s;
  return Buffer.concat([
    Buffer.from(r.toString(16).padStart(64, "0"), "hex"),
    Buffer.from(sLow.toString(16).padStart(64, "0"), "hex"),
  ]);
};

export const verify = (
  hashOfMessage: Buffer,
  publicKey: Buffer,
  signature: Buffer
) => {
  const r: bigint = bufferToBigInt(signature, 0, 32);
  const s: bigint = bufferToBigInt(signature, 32);
  const sModInverse: bigint = modInv(s, ORDER);
  const pointOne: Buffer = pointMultiply(
    GENERATOR_POINT,
    bufferToBigInt(hashOfMessage) * sModInverse
  );
  const pointTwo: Buffer = pointMultiply(publicKey, r * sModInverse);
  const pointResult: Buffer = pointAdd(pointOne, pointTwo);
  return extractX(pointResult) === r;
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my mistake.

I miscalculated `s` because I used `randomNumber` instead of `r`.

The calculation for `s` should have been as follows:

```
const s: bigint = modulo(
    modInv(randomNumber, ORDER) *
      (bufferToBigInt(hashOfMessage) + r * privateKeyAsNumber),
    ORDER
  );
```